# Could it be a biased voting if a Jewish person votes to delete an answer about ancient Israelites being immigrants in nowadays Israel (as to Genesis)?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have a question about my History Stack Exchange post: [Where were the ancient Israelites before they came to Israel (if they were new inhabitants at all)?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64017/where-were-the-ancient-israelites-before-they-came-to-israel-if-they-were-new-i)

Could it be a biased voting if a Jewish person votes to delete an answer about ancient Israelites being immigrants in nowadays Israel (as to Genesis)?

I am asking to undelete the answer since it is a senseful try to shed light upon what was going on in ancient days - even if a Bible text is not reliable and language and genetics are a better answer.

An answer does not have to be downvoted and deleted only because it seems wrong or its sources are partly doubtful. It surely adds value to the discussion thread since it shows the original biblical view, no matter how reliable a text of the Bible is.

*Mind that the Bible text is not my opinion, it is just the trigger and an important note in a conflict where beliefs are as important as facts.*

Comment: I see you haven't taken the site [tour] yet. If you had you might have noticed we are *not a discussion site*. So *'adding value to the discussion thread'* is a problem since there is no discussion thread. We only have questions and answers. Answers which can not support themselves with verifiable sources (see the [Historical Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method#:~:text=Historical%20method%20is%20the%20collection,write%20histories%20of%20the%20past.)) will tend to collect downvotes, and are often deleted.

Comment: Votes are private. Faith is private. Ethnicity is private. Heritage is private. I have no intent of exploring any theory that would change those things.

Comment: I suggest you think through ramifications of your approach to SE voting, for instance: (1) "Are Christians biased when voting to delete answers/questions  dealing with Christianity?", (2) "Are atheists biased when voting to delete any answers/question dealing with any type of religion?", (3) "Are Greeks biased when voting to delete any answers/question dealing with Greek history?", (4) "Are Whites (Caucasians if you  prefer)  biased when voting to delete any answers/question dealing with the history of Western civilization?" [These are rhetorical questions, please, do not bother answering.]

Comment: @MoisheKohan: They *might* be ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Could it be a biased voting if a Jewish person vote

Why are you singling out "Jewish"?

It's certainly possible that *any* user may be biased. However, that does not inherently invalidate their vote. An answer is deleted only by multiple votes. History.SE is a community moderated website. We trust our users to make collective determinations based on their knowledge and experience.

So even if you have evidence that a delete-voter was Jewish, which you don't, accusations of bias is not an argument to restore your answer. **Fixing up your answer to meet community expectations of quality is the only way to win support for undeletion.**

> An answer does not have to be downvoted and deleted only because it seems wrong or its sources are partly doubtful. It surely adds value to the discussion thread since it shows the original biblical view, no matter how reliable a text of the Bible is.

We are a Q&A site. An answers has to be downvoted if it is wrong. It should even be deleted if it is egrigiously wrong. The value we seek is adding factual answers to a question.

Lots of sources have incorrect views on things. They are not inherently valuable to us.